# Can I use a visa issued by the Netherlands (Schengen) to travel to Paris as my first entry?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, france, netherlands

I was issued a Schengen visa by the Netherlands embassy. I am on a two-week trip, the first week in the Netherlands and the second week in France. But at this moment I want to travel through as my first entry and then a train to Wageningen, which is my first week of stay before I get back to France for my final days and then back to Accra. Is it possible with the Schengen visa?

Answer (score 2):

That's fine; sseing as the Netherlands is your main destination, you have the correct visa.

To be safe, bring a train booking confirmation on the flight, to show French police if asked (which is unlikely)